# Is this an error?: ad-handle-definition: `mime-display-message' got redefined

Tags: emacs

Is this an error message, and if so should I be concerned about tracking down the root cause?

```
ad-handle-definition: `mime-display-message' got redefined
```

I do not see any similar problems reported in my searching Google.  I'm running Wanderlust for Emacs on OSX developer build post-24.3/pre-24.4.

Thanks.

Comment: No, its just saying that the function is advised somewhere in the code (for eg: init.el) and is activated now.

Comment: Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated -- now I can sleep easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`. . . /semi/site-lisp/semi/mime-view.el` contains a function entitled `mime-display-message` -- this function gets redefined in `. . ./share/emacs/site-lisp/w3m/mime-w3m.el`.

```
(let (current-load-list)
  (defadvice mime-display-message
    (after add-emacs-w3m-functions-to-pre/post-command-hook activate compile)
    "Advised by emacs-w3m.
Add some emacs-w3m utility functions to pre/post-command-hook."
    (when (featurep 'w3m)
      (w3m-make-local-hook 'pre-command-hook)
      (w3m-make-local-hook 'post-command-hook)
      (add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'w3m-store-current-position nil t)
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'mime-w3m-check-current-position nil t))))
```